Is 大記録 specific to baseball domain? What does it mean exactly?
I came across the following sentence in my textbook:
歴史的な大記録を作った斎藤{さいとう}選手は、祝福の拍手にこたえて帽子をとって軽くおじぎをした。
From the kanji themselves, it's clear that the word 大記録 means big or great 大 record 記録. My problem is that I couldn't confirm this by using dictionaries because I couldn't find the word there. I found out this entry in 連想類語辞典 that seems to relate the world specifically to baseball as well:

（甲子園の）大記録 ⇒ 名誉や名声を得て華々しい状態である（すぐれた業績）
(Koushien [stadium]) big record ⇒ the state of having obtained honours and fame (outstanding performance or achievement)

For this reason, I am inclined to believe this word 大記録 is a specific term used only in baseball. Did I get the meaning right, and is my assumption on the scope of the word correct? Could you provide more example sentences where 大記録 is used in a natural way?

No, 大記録 is just "big record", and it's not a baseball-specific term. It's not listed in dictionaries simply because it's a simple combination of the prefix 大 and 記録. Similarly, I believe words like 大成功, 大問題, 大爆発, 大飢饉, 大地震, 大冒険 and so on are not included in dictionaries.
